# Can you summon shades in the Grand Cathedral after defeating the Burnt Ivory King?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In most places it is possible to summon shades (small white soap stone) after defeating an area boss. Before defeating the boss, I saw an abundance of shades available to summon. However, now that I have defeated him, I can not find any.

Is it possible to summon shades (for help with Elysium Soul farming) in the Grand Cathedral after the Burnt Ivory King is defeated?  If so, can they go into the chaos with you to farm or will they unsummon like they do other places when you cross the boss fog door of a defeated boss?

Comment: You can only summon people using the small white soapstone. You can't summon people who are using the regular soapstone once you've defeated an area boss.

Comment: @slow_excellence that what shades are.

Comment: @Ben - oh duh, I didn't even realize it until now. Either way you can't summon them once you beat the boss though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot summon shades after defeating the boss in the Grand Cathedral.

My tests:

I stayed in the Grand Cathedral for about 30 minutes. I found 0 signs.  I was able to find signs in other places of the DLC.

I had a friend (who I was able to summon in other areas) put his small white soap down, and I was never able to see his sign. I tried for about 5 minutes with this test.